# After publish node send email to someone

Tags: drupal-7, hook

Let's say i have a custom module in D7 , i want to add a feature to  this .

the feature is : when a user publish a node send an email to someone .

```
<?php
function sending_email_node_update($node) {
  if (isset($node->original->status) && $node->original->status == 0 && $node->status == 1) {
    drupal_mail('sending_email', 'sending_email_node_update', 'soheilsadeghbayan@yahoo.com', language_default());
 }
}
function sending_mail_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'sending_email_node_update':
      $message['subject'] = t('this is my action report');
      $message['body'][] = t('this is a reporting from sending email made by soheil') ;
      break;
  }
}
?>
```

No email send !!!
Could you please help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

@Soheil You can use `Rules` module to achieve this. Create rule event when particular content type's node has been published and in action block trigger the mail.

Bit late but hope that helps others... :)